# Can we place the facebook script reference in the head section?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

To get the facebook comment count, I'm doing this:

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=555555&amp;xfbml=1">
</script> 

<fb:comments href="<%: url %>" num_posts="15" width="518">
</fb:comments>
```

I have this in many places so is it okay to place the fb-root and script reference in the head section or in a master page (I'm using asp.net mvc) instead of placing it next to the fb:comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. you can put a script reference in head. and have one fb-root in the document (beginning of body seems like a good place). all fb: tags will then be parsed once the script loads.

Comment: Does it matter where we place it?  Would it be okay to place it in the end?  Placing it in the end seems to work fine for my comments, but for the FB.api, it says fb-root div not found.

Comment: are you initializing with FB.init?